# Did the Spanish Civil War influence in any way the contents of the RAE's dictionary?

Tags: historia, rae, dle

While browsing the results of a search in [the NTLLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) I have noticed that the results can be looked up in RAE's dictionaries from 1914, 1925, 1936, 1939, 1947, 1956... The mean time between two consecutive editions of the dictionary is around 10 years, with the exceptions of the editions from 1936 and 1939, that coincide with the beginning and the end of the Spanish Civil War. So I'm curious about the possibility of the war itself or its outcome to have influenced the contents of the dictionary.

Nonetheless, in the RAE's web page [you can read](http://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/diccionarios/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola) about the editions of the dictionary. The editions are listed like this:

```
Ed. #  Name                               Year
-----------------------------------------------------
...
15     Diccionario de la lengua española  1925
16     Diccionario de la lengua española  [1936] 1939
17     Diccionario de la lengua española  1947
...
```

So in 1936 and 1939 it seems that it was the same edition being published (the 16th) and that just a prologue was added. This seems clearer if you read [the institution's cronology](http://www.rae.es/la-institucion/historia/siglo-xx):

> **1936**. The sixteenth edition of the dictionary of the Spanish language is published, which will reappear —with an additional prologue— in 1939, after the civil war.

But if you read on, you notice that the war did exert an influence over the academy itself:

> **1936**. Because of the war, several academics [...] leave for exile.
>
> **1937**. In December, the Government of Burgos, commanded by General Franco, created the Institute of Spain, which brings together the dissolved academies.

So I'm curious: did then the Spanish Civil War influence the contents of the dictionary beyond that added prologue? What did the war modify in the dictionary between 1936 and 1939?

---

<sup><sub>Answers can be written in English or Spanish, whichever you feel more confident about.</sub></sup>

Comment: This is just a thing I've heard... that once Franco starts his dictatorship, the RAE was mainly composed by members supporting him, right wingers that largely included subjects through terminology like heraldry. I just put it as a comment because I don't know if there's actual data about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He encontrado una página que habla sobre las diferentes versiones de los diccionarios de la (Real) Academia.

En 1936 estaba lista la nueva edición del diccionario y de hecho se imprimió poco antes de estallar la guerra civil pero no se puso en circulación.

> La edición 16ª de este Diccionario, cuya impresión se terminó en 1936,
>   aunque, por haber estallado poco después la guerra civil, no llegara a
>   ponerse en circulación hasta 1939

Después de la guerra se añadio un prólogo y se cambiaron las portadas volviendo a ser Real Academia ya que había perdido la condición de "real" durante la república, el prólogo no tiene desperdicio:

> «Advertencia. La presente edición del Diccionario estaba en vísperas
>   de salir a la venta cuando las hordas revolucionarias, que, al
>   servicio de poderes exóticos, pretendían sumir a España para siempre
>   en la ruina y en la abyección, se enfrentaron en julio de 1936 con el
>   glorioso Alzamiento Nacional. Perseguidas con diabólica saña bajo la
>   tiranía marxista cuantas instituciones encarnaban el verdadero
>   espíritu de nuestro pueblo, no se podía esperar que la vesania de los
>   usurpadores del poder respetase la vida de la Academia. Fue disuelta,
>   en efecto, de un plumazo; y aunque no tardó en renacer en las tierras
>   privilegiadas de nuestra patria que conocieron las primeras el
>   alborear de la reconquista, la casa solariega de la Corporación, su
>   patrimonio y sus publicaciones quedaron secuestrados en la capital de
>   la nación hasta el día felicísimo de su liberación total. Mientras
>   tanto, la casa editorial que tenía en depósito las publicaciones de la
>   Academia se vio obligada a poner en circulación un corto número de
>   ejemplares del nuevo Diccionario, que, naturalmente, llevan la fecha
>   de 1936; pero, al hacerse hoy cargo la Corporación de los ejemplares
>   restantes, al mismo tiempo que recobra, con íntima satisfacción, el
>   uso de sus emblemas tradicionales y su título varias veces secular de
>   Real Academia Española, quiere que la 16ª edición de su Diccionario se
>   difunda ya por el mundo con el sello de la nueva España imperial. Por
>   eso se ha cambiado el primer pliego de la obra y se le ha puesto como
>   fecha la del glorioso Año de la Victoria, 1939. Se observará que, en
>   las páginas preliminares, se ha omitido la acostumbrada lista de
>   académicos con la mención del cargo que ejercen en la Corporación.
>   Esta lista no habría podido hacerse hasta quedar definitivamente
>   constituída la Academia en fecha que señalan sus estatutos para la
>   elección de los cargos, y ello vendría a aumentar en varios meses el
>   retraso ya considerable con que se pone a la venta esta edición. La
>   misma preocupación de salir al encuentro con nuestra diligencia al
>   anhelo del público por disponer del nuevo Diccionario ha hecho que se
>   prescinda también de insertar las listas de las academias
>   correspondientes, pues las probables alteraciones ocurridas en el seno
>   de aquéllas durante más de tres años sólo serán conocidas con certeza
>   cuando en el curso próximo se reanude con dichas academias la
>   colaboración que tan fecunda viene siendo para los fines que
>   perseguimos en común y que, ahora más que nunca, habrá se ser
>   particularmente estrecha y cordial»

Aparte de eso el contenido no sufrió cambio alguno y se mantuvo la edición del 36 tal como se imprimió en su momento. La siguiente edición, la de 1947 fue una reimpresión de la anterior.

> En 1947 la decimoséptima edición se limita a reimprimir la edición de
>   1936, difundida principalmente a partir de 1939 y agotada rápidamente,
>   lo cual demuestra que el nuevo régimen salido de la guerra civil no
>   tenía mayor inconveniente en asumir íntegramente el diccionario
>   académico tal como había quedado publicado tras haber sido redactado
>   durante cinco años en tiempos de la República.

Con esto podemos decir que la guerra no influyó en el diccionario en si mismo ya que el contenido se había impreso antes y no se modificó nada, los cambios son más bien estéticos, la portada con su de nuevo *Real Academia* y el escudo con la corona y el prólogo alabando el nuevo régimen.

---

<sub>Fuente: http://www.filosofia.org/enc/aca/aca.htm</sub>

Comment: Qué gracia el uso que hace de _exótico_