# ¿Existe algún adjetivo o título equivalente a "Real" que pueda ser usado en contextos no monárquicos?

Tags: adjetivos, rae

Al hilo de la reciente pregunta sobre [las ediciones del DLE pre y pos Guerra Civil](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/did-the-spanish-civil-war-influence-in-any-way-the-contents-of-the-raes-diction), veo que la **Real Academia Española**:

[image]

pasó en 1936 a llamarse simplemente **Academia Española**:

[image]

En mi opinión, aunque sea solamente por estética, el segundo nombre queda un poco triste, como muy poco diferenciado de cualquier otra academia de España. Le falta algo que la distinga como "la" Academia.

Me surge entonces la duda: ¿qué otra palabra podría usarse en lugar de "Real", que transmita el mismo sentido de oficialidad, pero sin connotaciones monárquicas o, directamente, sin connotaciones políticas (i.e. no valdría tampoco "Republicana Academia Española")?

Comment: A veces: *sagrado*.

Comment: En Chile se usa bastante "_Ilustre_" para darle "título" a algo o alguien que no lo tiene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Qué tal la propia palabra ***[oficial](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QvWA4QX)***?

> 1. adj. Que emana de la autoridad del Estado. *Documento, lengua, noticia oficial.*
> 2. adj. Dicho de una institución, de un edificio, de un centro de enseñanza, etc.: Que se sufraga con fondos públicos y está bajo la dependencia del Estado o de las entidades territoriales.

Así, podrías hablar de la "Academia oficial española" o "Academia española oficial" o incluso de la "Academia oficial de la lengua española" (AOLE).

Si no, también tienes ***[estatal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GnQWPN3)***:

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al Estado.

En todo caso, aparte de la Real Academia Española ninguna otra academia lleva adjetivo alguno en su nombre, tan solo el gentilicio del país al que pertenecen:

- Real Academia Española
- Academia Colombiana de la Lengua
- Academia Ecuatoriana de la Lengua
- Academia Mexicana de la Lengua
- Academia Salvadoreña de la Lengua
- Academia Venezolana de la Lengua
- Academia Chilena de la Lengua
- Academia Peruana de la Lengua
- Academia Guatemalteca de la Lengua
- Academia Costarricense de la Lengua
- Academia Filipina de la Lengua Española
- Academia Panameña de la Lengua
- Academia Cubana de la Lengua
- Academia Paraguaya de la Lengua Española
- Academia Boliviana de la Lengua
- Academia Dominicana de la Lengua
- Academia Nicaragüense de la Lengua
- Academia Argentina de Letras
- Academia Nacional de Letras de Uruguay
- Academia Hondureña de la Lengua
- Academia Puertorriqueña de la Lengua Española
- Academia Norteamericana de la Lengua Española
- Academia Ecuatoguineana de la Lengua Española